# Page not found (404) in django url

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

This is my views.py

```
def delete(request, id):
    employee = User.objects.get(id=id)
    employee.delete()
    return redirect('show')
```

This is My urls.py

```
url(r'^delete/<int:id>', core_views.delete),
```

This is models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Employee(models.Model):
    eid = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    eemail = models.EmailField()
    econtact = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "employee"
```

Comment: Please post full traceback with `DEBUG` on.

Answer (score 0):

Correct the url as follows

```
url(r'^delete/<int:id>/$', core_views.delete),
```

Change the view also as shown below

```
def delete(request, id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Employee, id=id)
    instance.delete()
    return redirect('show')
```

Comment: please post your models file

Comment: I added model file above question. Please check

Comment: I have updated the answer, user is not linked to your models, so if you want to delete the employee you have to write the code this way, otherwise add user as foreignkey to employee model

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use **delete()** for custom method name in your **views** script

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Employee

def deleteAction(request, pk):
    employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=pk)
    employee.delete()
    return redirect('show')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not trying to delete an `Employee` object, but a `User` one, which are not the same things at all. Maybe you forgot to link a `user` as a `OneToOneField`?

The simplest would be to use class based view, in your case a `DeleteView`:

```py
from django.views.generic import DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from models import Employee

class DeleteEmployee(DeleteView):
   model = Employee
   success_url = reverse_lazy('show')
```

In your `urls.py` :

```py
urlpatterns = [
    # [...]
    path('delete', views.DeleteEmployee.as_view(), name='delete_employee'),
]
```

Notice that I used `path` instead of `url`, much simpler to use with no regex here.